# Why do some people have high blood pressure and others have low, constantly?

Tags: blood-pressure

Is this genetic? On what factors does it depend whether I am going to have high or low blood pressure?

Comment: I'm wondering if this question should just be "*what causes high and low blood pressure, and how to maintain a healthy blood pressure*".  No, I'm not talking about with dogs either... in humans...humans.... spooky humans!!! Lions, tigers, and humans, oh my!!